# assert that a view is to the right of another view

Tags: android, android-testing

In a linear layout with 2 views A and B, how do I assert that view B is to the right of view A?

Comment: if it is a horizontal linearlayout, you put B after A, then B will in the right of A. if it is a vertical linearlayout, it will be top bottom. In relativeLayout, you can have android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/id_A" in B to make sure B is at right of A.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can check it with `view1.getX() < view2.getX()`

If you want to perform automatic View assertions, the simpler way is to use Espresso.
In your case, une it with your own matcher looking at the X position of a view

https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso

Comment: Use `isLeftOf(Mather<View> matcher)` and other from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/assertion/PositionAssertions.html

Answer (score 1):

Why to invent the bicycle - there are [Position assertions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/assertion/PositionAssertions.html) provided by Google in android.support.test.espresso.assertion library. Use `isRightOf(Matcher<View> matcher)` method.

Answer (score 0):

when **A** and **B** are childs of **layout** just do

```
if(layout.indexOfChild(B) > layout.indexOfChild(A)) {
    // B at right of A
} else {
    // B at left of A
}
```

this works in horizonal orientation

Comment: Use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/assertion/PositionAssertions.html